# Bug with "insertRule"?

Tags: javascript, css

I have Javascript code, modified from "Javascript: The Definitive Guide" (pages 442-444 or kindle location 14998), which creates a CSS style sheet and inserts rules.  But I find that using the standardized approach it promotes does not work in Chrome:

[JSFiddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/Mystagogue/N7qzM/1/)

If the above code is run in Chrome, only the word "You!" turns orange.  If I introduce an ugly hack, then it works ok in Chrome:

[JSFiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/Mystagogue/N7qzM/)

Is this an error in the book, a bug in Chrome, or I messed up?

*NOTE* I am intentionally not using a library (e.g. jquery, etc.) for this exercise.

Comment: Why not just let jquery do this for you?

Comment: I added a "no library" note to the question, to clarify. :)

Comment: The code provided in Flanagan's book (6th edition) works because it *either* modifies the `.innerHTML` of a new stylesheet *or* uses `.insertRule()`/`.addRule()`. It doesn't use both. It creates a *new* stylesheet for *every* `addCSSRule` call. I guess `.innerHTML` doesn't work well with [DOM CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html). (By the way, your code doesn't work in Firefox 10 and IE7-9).

Comment: @Zeta code works in IE8 (yes, it is IE8, not an IE9 in IE8 mode) on WinXP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line `styleElt.innerHTML = styles;` in

```
if (typeof styles === "string") {
// The argument is stylesheet text
if (styleElt) {
    styleElt.innerHTML = styles;
} else {
```

Recreates `styleSheet` object. `styleSheet.styleSheet`'s value becomes detached from the document, which results in loss of all previously declared style rules.

Firefox works the same way as Chrome, so it looks like this is not a bug.